# Leaflet running fine on the console but not able to publish rmd document

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown

I have this error when trying to deploy an rmd document. My code chunk runs ok and in console and the whole document looks good but when publishing i get this error "Error cannot open connection".

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
map<-read.csv("map.csv")
shortmap<-data.frame(lat=rep(map$lat, map$Uniques000), long=rep(map$long, map$Uniques000), Uniques000=1)
library (leaflet)
leaflet(shortmap) %>% 
addTiles() %>%
clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```
````

I tried deploying the rmd document with the examples provided in the leaflet page and that works fine so it is something wrong with my code as something gets lost when deploying it.

Sorry I can't provide a replicate example I am just looking for suggestions on the connectivity side as that appears to be the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move all my data sources to a new code chunk at the top of the document and then refer to them on all the other code chunks. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`---
title: "leaflet"
output: html_document
---`

try to stick that at the top of your .Rmd

Comment: no is not that I have those parameters on top of my document